# Get data-id value of textbox on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox set-up, like so:

```
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewVehCode, new {data_id = "" })
```

When a user selects a vehicle, the description of the vehicle becomes the value of the textbox and the vehicle code (which is what I want to send to DB) becomes the data-id (not full code but I set the values like this):

```
        $("#NewVehCode").val(vehDescription);
        $("#NewVehCode").attr("data-id", vehCode);
```

This all works fine, except for the fact that when I submit, MVC grabs the value of the textbox.

Is there a way I can on submit, get the data-id of that textbox instead of the value?

Note that I'm not using .js to gather the data. Form calls a controller action that sends the model directly to the controller.

Comment: A form only submits the name/value pairs of its successful controls. It does not send `data=*` attribute values. Add another property to your model and set the value of that property to `vehCode` if you want to submit both

Comment: You mention "selecting" a vehicle; why are you not using a select element with options instead, where you can have the value of the option be the ID?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, your comment helped me come up with a solution (see my own answer).

Comment: Hi Mads, due to structure and volume of data, we are using a grid in a pop-up to select a vehicle. A dropdown would not be sensible in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen Muecke's comment helped me trigger this solution:

I've added a hidden textbox to use for the vehicle code, and made the textbox that shows the description a standard textbox with no data binding.

```
        <input id="newVehInput" readonly="readonly" class="longInput" type="text">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewVehCode, new { style = "display: none"})
```

This way I can use the value with no issues:

```
        $("#newVehInput").val(vehDescription);
        $("#NewVehCode").val(vehCode);
```

(Will mark as answer in 2 days)

Comment: rather than using input you should use hidden filed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to submit values of "data" properties. I am not sure why you wanted to use data property (is that a requirement or not, not sure). But you can have a hidden property in the form so, when user selects a vehicle, along with data property of text box , update this hidden value. This hidden value will be submitted back to form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden textbox to your html which you post back on submit

In your model:

```
public string Id {get;set;}
```

Render it in the view with a hidden class

And with js.

```
$("#vehicleList").on("change",function(){
$("#Id").val($vehCode)
})
```

When you submit the value of id should be set in your model

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `hidden field` hold the Updated value.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiddenVehCode" name="HiddenVehCode" Value="0"/>
```

**JS**

```
$("#HiddenVehCode").val(vehDescription);
```

Note: you should have the model set up so that HiddenVehCode will reach the actionMethod on Form Submit.Something Like,

```
public int HiddenVehCode {get;set;}
```